# Plotly Express Python

Tags: python, plotly

Estoy haciendo una representación con plotly express y me sale correctamente pero me gustaría cambiar los colores que trae por defecto.

Este es el código:

```
fig = go.bar(df2_participation_v2_, x="id", y="count", color='action', 
barmode='group',height=400)

plotly.offline.plot(fig, filename='test.html')
```

Obtengo algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me gustaría poder cambiar el color por defecto y poder elegir mediante rgb los que quiero, si no es posible con esta librería(con la que se dibuja esto de manera muy rápida y sencilla) estaría abierto a otras.

Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con el parámetro `color_discrete_sequence` puedes especificar una lista de cadenas, que sean colores válidos en CSS (nombres de colores como `"white"` o RGB hex como `"#ffffff"`).

Por ejemplo (no tengo tus datos así que uso unos que trae de ejemplo `px`):

```
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.iris()
fig = px.bar(df, x="sepal_length", y="petal_width", color='species',
             barmode='group',height=400,
             color_discrete_sequence=["#ffdd88", "#88dd44", "#4477dd"])
fig.show()
```

Sale:

[image: Resultado]